# Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares

I'm trying to implement iteratively reweighted least squares.

Looking at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), I don't understand the following line

$\boldsymbol\beta^{(t+1)}
 =
\underset{\boldsymbol\beta}{ \operatorname{arg\,min} }
    \sum_{i=1}^n w_i^{(t)}  \left| y_i - X_i \boldsymbol\beta \right|^2
 =
(X^{\rm T} W^{(t)} X)^{-1} X^{\rm T} W^{(t)} \mathbf{y}$

shouldn't weighted linear least squares rather look like this:

$\boldsymbol\beta^{(t+1)}
 =
\underset{\boldsymbol\beta}{ \operatorname{arg\,min} }
    \sum_{i=1}^n w_i^{(t)}  \left| y_i - X_i \boldsymbol\beta \right|^2
 =
((W^{(t)} X)^{\rm T} (W^{(t)} X))^{-1} W^{(t)} \mathbf{y}$

with $W^{(t)}$ containing the square-roots of weights $w_i^{(t)}$?

or are these equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we define the following vector/matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
r &= X\beta - y \qquad&({\rm residual/error\,vector}) \\
R &= {\rm Diag}(r) \qquad&({\rm as\,a\,diagonal\,matrix}) \\
W &= {\rm Diag}(w) \qquad&({\rm weights\,as\,a\,matrix}) \\
}$$
then the objective function can be written without explicit summations as
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= W:R^2 \\
}$$
where the colon is a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A$$
Calculate the gradient of the function.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= W:(2R\,dR) \\
 &= 2WR:dR \\
 &= 2\,{\rm diag}(WR):{\rm diag}(dR) \\
 &= 2Wr:dr \\
 &= 2W(X\beta - y):(X\,d\beta) \\
 &= 2X^TW(X\beta - y):d\beta \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\beta} &= 2X^TW(X\beta - y) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $\beta$.
$$\eqalign{
X^TWX\beta &= X^TWy \\
\beta &= (X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWy \\
}$$
This confirms the Wikipedia result.